# Laravel mail send Amazon SES no longer supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, ssl, amazon-ses

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with PHP 5.6.40 on Ubuntu EC2. I have a very large project that cannot be updated in few hours or days.
My server version OpenSSL 1.1.1 and I've done a test from my PC to my website using `curl --tlsv1.2 mywebsite.com` and I got a successful response with the HTML page.
I also checked the version of OpenSSL on my Ubuntu using

```
openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.com:443 -tls1_2
```

I got 'CONNECTED' response. Also I checked Swift Mailer version 5.4.12 supporting tls1.2.

But `mail::send` in Laravel is crashing with error exception `Swift_TransportException`
with message `Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 Access denied: Amazon SES no longer supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. You must update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above.`

I don't know what's causing the problem if all the versions I checked are supporting tls 1.2. PHP: 5.6.40, Openssl: 1.1.11

Comment: I've voted this up in the hope that somebody else experienced this error. However, please understand that we don't have access to your software config so help may be limited. I was thinking about maybe something is forcing an older connection such as DH certs, but that seems unlikely even to me...

Comment: Did you look at the discussion here? https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/598

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved:
If you have a correct version of open ssl, php and tls1.2 enabled in your server but still facing this issue in swiftmailer

Go to laravel root then vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport

open streambuffer.php find startTLS() function

replace it with

public function startTLS()
{
return stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);
}

now swift will use only tls 1.2

This is a solution using php 5.6 and laravel 5.1